# Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I was wondering if the instructions given for an essay test is correct.

"Choose one from the topics listed below."

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct.

In common usage (U.S. at least) you are more likely to hear "Choose one **of** the topics..."

The two are interchangeable, but the version on the test is slightly more formal.

Answer (score 0):

In AusE we would also generally say *Choose one of the topics listed below*, or less redundantly, *Choose one of the topics below*, or *Choose one of the topics listed*, but I haven't looked at a formal exam paper for a long time.